# How to use PHOG and LPQ features for Emotion Recognition?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, svm

I have a database that consists of PHOG and LPQ features for each image. Now, I wish to train an SVM on these features for emotion recognition i.e SVM classifies the images on basis of emotion in the image.

Please provide a detailed procedure on how to use these features to train SVM.

Comment: It's hard to know how to answer this.  What specifically are you uncertain about?  What research have you done, and what approaches have you considered?  What are you unsure about?  Right now it's not clear what is preventing you from knowing how to do this on your own, so it's not clear how to help you. Please edit the question to tell us what approaches you've considered and why you've rejected them. The obvious answer is "just do it"; those are your features; now train a SVM on a training set, and see how it works.  Have you tried it?  Do you have some specific concern or uncertainty?

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To train your SVM inevitably you need some baseline, which can be accquired from [FERA 2011 contest](http://sspnet.eu/fera2011/). The whole procedure using this data is described in [Emotion Recognition Using PHOG and LPQ features](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~aasthana/Papers/FERA11.pdf) by Abhinav Dhall, Akshay Asthana, Roland Goecke and Tom Gedeon. After reading that there is a follow up [FERA 2015](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszmv/Documents/FERA2015.pdf).

Comment: I am sorry for mainly links and references but the procedure is very vast (too broad to sum it up) and well described already.